# Undefined Offset Array

Tags: php, arrays, offset

when I run this code I get **Notice: Undefined offset: 3 On line 12 and 18. 12 and 18 with** in front.

```
$_SESSION['basket'][3];

if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "add")
{
    if(isset($_GET['product_id']))
    {
        **$_SESSION['basket'][3] += 4;**
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['basket'][3] += 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is output of `print_r($_SESSION)` ?

Comment: Which one is line no 12 and 18..

Comment: The line `$_SESSION['basket'][3];` does not in fact do *anything* at all.

Comment: Its only when I run the page first time, when I run it after the first time the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize value at 3rd index.

```
$_SESSION['basket'][3] = 0;
```

Or the better solution is

```
$_SESSION['basket'][3] = isset($_SESSION['basket'][3]) ? $_SESSION['basket'][3] : 0;
```

Instead of only

```
$_SESSION['basket'][3];
```

Answer (score -1):

Thing is that you are not initialising the session

Try initialise it like this

```
$_SESSION['baslet'][3] = 0;
```

now for

```
$_SESSION['basket'][3] += 4;
```

try it like this

```
$_SESSION['basket'][3] = intval($_SESSION['basket'][3]) + 4;
```

better always convert data into integer type or float type before mathematical opearations

Comment: Stop downvoting my answers @manwal